# What is the difference between two unanswered-questions links?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

In following picture you can see two links saying **Unanswered**. Are they both same? Whats the difference in them? When I click on them saw different results.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top is link to the Unanswered questions list.

The bottom is meant to sort the existing list (whatever it is) showing only unanswered questions.

Just rephrasing the other answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

The top one is for all unanswered questions.

The bottom one is for all unanswered questions in your current context.  So if you're viewing a tag, it will show you the unanswered questions for that tag.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on [the upper **Unanswered** button](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), you have different tabs to actually filter the unanswered questions more:
[**my tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags), [**newest**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest), [**votes**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) and [**no answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

If you click there on [**newest**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest), you should get the same questions as when you click on [the **unanswered** tab of the **Questions** page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered).