# What's difference between "Questions" tab's newest and "Unanswered" tab's newest subtabs?

Tags: support, questions, tabs

There is "newest" sub-tab in both tabs.

1. [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)
2. [Unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)

What's difference between two different logic? Which questions those tab's give?

Also why "Questions" tab also have [unanswered subtab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) though there is ["Unanswered" Main tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)?
Answer->For this [What is the difference between two unanswered-questions links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80869/178505) answered me somewhat. Though if there is better explanation it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) will show all questions ordered by ask date in descending order (newest first).
The [unanswered newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) will show all questions **with no upvoted answers** ordered by ask date in descending order (newest first).

You can see what questions are the current tab is listing from here:

> [image]

Comment: Means only questions having answers received and they are having votes. Those will not be reflected in Unanswered tab. I asked question because I have seen questions having answers also shown in Unanswered tab. I wasn't knowing don't require votes to show in Unanswered newest tab. :(  Thanks